# Node.js: res.send on a signedUrl string returns {} in production

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, digital-ocean

I'm trying to build a small Node.js API hosted on PaaS service Digital Ocean App Platform. The API is very simple: only having a single route that I know is accessible. However, what I do in this route only works in my machine in development mode. When I deploy it, it ceases to work as I'd want to.

For more context, this route takes a string path and returns a signed URL to my Cloudfront instance. I'm using the `aws-cloudfront-sign` library and what I'm trying to return is the signed URL directly after calling `cfsign.getSignedUrl`. In development and on my machine, I indeed receive a valid URL. But deployed and in production I only receive `{}` after accessing the URL.

I validated by making quick res.send() calls that the `signingParams` are correctly instantiated and correctly include my private key. Same for the imagePath parameter.

Here's the route:

```js
"use strict";

// Thanks to: https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/developer/creating-amazon-cloudfront-signed-urls-in-node-js/
// And also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-canned-policy.html#private-content-canned-policy-creating-signature
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cfsign = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');

const twoMinutes = 2*60*1000;

let key = ""
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
  key = 'localOnlyKey';
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  key = process.env.CLOUDFRONT_API_SECRET;
}

/*
  Convert an image path to a full-fledged Cloudfront URL
*/
router.get("/:imagePath", (req, res, next) => {
  const expirationTime = Date.now() + twoMinutes;

  const signingParams = {
    keypairId: 'K34YSMTSIK8T2F',
    privateKeyString: key,
    expireTime: expirationTime
  };
  
  const imagePath = req.params.imagePath;

  // Generating a signed URL
  const signedUrl = cfsign.getSignedUrl(
      `https://d3dzfh5brk23pn.cloudfront.net/${req.params.imagePath}`,
      signingParams
  );

  res.send(signedUrl);
});

module.exports = router;
```

What could lead to this route only producing a single `{}` response?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `CLOUDFRONT_API_SECRET ` is provided?

Comment: Yes it is, and it looks like it is interpreted correctly because if I do `res.send(signingParams)` they are correctly returned. Including `CLOUDFRONT_API_SECRET ` 

Comment: Be careful with any space in `CLOUDFRONT_API_SECRET` value. Space character is not legal in a private key string.

Comment: Oh, I think that was it… I just stopped using CLOUDFRONT_API_SECRET and that fixed it! Thank you for the suggestion 